# SwiftUI: The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time

Tags: swiftui, uicolor, cgcolor

I want to get the calendar color from EKEvent. But i´m getting the Error:
*The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions*
The Rectangle().fill causes the Error.
How do i get the UIColor from calendar.cgcolor for the Rectangle?

```
           ForEach(0..<data.eventsByDay.prefix(4).count)
            {(section) in
              
                HStack(alignment: .bottom){
                    ForEach(0..<data.eventsByDay[section].prefix(3).count)
                    {(row) in
                        
                        Rectangle().fill(UIColor(cgcgolor: data.eventsByDay[section][row].calendar.cgcolor))
                        .frame(width: 3, height: 26, alignment: .leading)
                        .cornerRadius(1.5)
                        .padding(.bottom, 1.0)
                    }
             }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when Xcode cannot determine the exact cause of the error.

I suggest you the following instruction from the error

> try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

You can do that by moving part of your view into a separate function or `View`, but also you can comment out blocks one by one until you see the actual error or until it builds: in this case, the error is on one of the commented lines.

---

In his case, you can comment out both `ForEach`s and replace them with constants:

```
//ForEach(0..<data.eventsByDay.prefix(4).count)
//{(section) in
    let section = 0
    HStack(alignment: .bottom){
//        ForEach(0..<data.eventsByDay[section].prefix(3).count)
//        {(row) in
            let row = 0
            Rectangle().fill(UIColor(cgcgolor: data.eventsByDay[section][row].calendar.cgcolor))
                .frame(width: 3, height: 26, alignment: .leading)
                .cornerRadius(1.5)
                .padding(.bottom, 1.0)
        }
    }
}
```

Then Xcode will be able to tell you that you've made a typo in the `UIColor` initializer(`cgColor` instead of `cgcgolor`), and that `fill` takes `Color` instead of `UIColor` - second one is from `UIKit` and with SwiftUI it will almost never will be needed.

So fixed variant looks like:

```
ForEach(0..<data.eventsByDay.prefix(4).count)
{(section) in
    let section = 0
    HStack(alignment: .bottom){
        ForEach(0..<data.eventsByDay[section].prefix(3).count)
        {(row) in
            let row = 0
            Rectangle().fill(Color(data.eventsByDay[section][row].calendar.cgcolor))
                .frame(width: 3, height: 26, alignment: .leading)
                .cornerRadius(1.5)
                .padding(.bottom, 1.0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With -> Rectangle().fill(Color it works. I´ve tried it before with cgColor, but didn`t know to use Color instead od UIColor ... Perefct, Thank you so much!

Comment: The key insight here is that the “unable to type-check” error message can be a **side effect** of some other mistake or error. Replacing `ForEach` with a constant or commenting out chucks of code piece by piece is a great way to simplify the expression enough for SwiftUI to accurately detect the underlying error. Thank you!